# Word classification?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, terminology

I am trying to understand what the word classification would be to name a variable for a program. I will have a label variable which will hold one of two values (correct/incorrect) but I don't how to describe these words. Such as: run is a verb, color is an adjective but what would be the words correct and incorrect fall under?

Comment: Consider "status".

Comment: "correct" and "incorrect" are both adjectives so that's probably not what you're after. Maybe you want "boolean" ?

Comment: @DanBron: I understand what you are thinking but I not sure of a better way to word what I was trying to say. I'm not looking for someone to name a variable for me, of that I very much by myself. I was looking for the of those two words. As such: If I were to have a mathmatical problem and I was to explain to a child that the answer is correct/incorrect what kind of word am I using?

Comment: @TroyPilewski I see. A *binary question*, then. Perhaps a *factual question*.

Comment: @DanBron This started because I was developing a flash card math application for my son and in detailness/pickyness could not best word to use to describe what these word were called to name a variable. Although, I do like the choice that (Graffito) came up with as a status.

Comment: Sounds good. I've retracted my close vote.  If you like *status*, you can add it as a "self-answer", as long as you also quote the relevant dictionary definition & name the dictionary you got it from.  You can then "accept" that answer, so future visitors who have the same question can see it's the word which worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this would be the best classification of the word in the sense that I am trying to use it.

State:  A condition or mode of being, as with regard to circumstances

[American Heritage Dictionary. 5th Edition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/state)

Answer (score 0):

The **Value** of *correct* or *incorrect* is, in fact, boolean. The specifics of whether the values allowed are adjectives are unimportant in the use as a yes/no answer.

> Mathematics: A quantity or number expressed by an algebraic term.

[American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/value)

Comment: Wouldn't this describe the integer answer rather than the word correct/incorrect?

Comment: _Correct_ is a value accepted in that field. It is then exchanged for true / false or 1 / 0.

Comment: I'm not looking for a value to put there. I'm looking to understand how you would describe the word correct/incorrect. As such: If I were to have a mathmatical problem and I was to explain to a child that the answer the child came up with is correct/incorrect what kind of word would I be using if I said "The answer is correct" or the " The answer is incorrect, find the correct answer."?

Comment: In what I explained to Dan Bron in the Flash Card App I was developing. In pickyness/detailness I did not understand what to call the two words to properly name a variable. I still do not understand what classification these word fall under. Are they adjectives which describe a value? Are they verbs?

Comment: The word _correct_ is an adjective when you say the child is correct, the answer is correct, but not in your original question.  There, you asked for a "label variable which will hold one of two values (correct/incorrect)". However, a computer program does not make such distinctions. They just expect a value, like a blob, known as a literal string which is taken as is -- unscreened for whether it is an adjective or not.

Comment: I apologize it looks like I have poorly worded my question. I understand now thank you!